# Pipe, fork, execl: bad file descriptors

Tags: c, linux

The goal is to create a pipe which execute "first" and "second" commands as `first | second` , but i get bad file descriptor errors. I've read different topic on stackoverflow about the way to build the pipe, and I tried to use the same logic with the file descriptor vectors here, but without results. Could you help me to understand which is the error?
my view:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* error message with exit */
void err (const char msg[])
{
    printf ("%s", msg);
    exit (-1);
}

#define BASH "/bin/bash"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* variables */
    pid_t pid;
    FILE *fp;
    char *token, *buffer;
    char first[128], second[128];
    int sz;

    int pfd[2];
    int read_fd = pfd[0];
    int write_fd = pfd[1];

    if (argc != 2)
        err ("Invalid number of args");

    /* open file and copy content in a buffer */
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r+");

    /* find end of file, get size, rewind */
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell (fp);
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    /* allocate enough space */
    buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * (sz));
    fread (buffer, 1, sz, fp);
    buffer[sz] = '\0';

    /* parse  commands strings
    *
    * first line
    */
    token = strtok (buffer, "\n");
    strcpy (first, token);

    /* second line */
    token = strtok (NULL, "\n");
    strcpy (second, token);
    printf ("%s", second);

    fclose (fp);

    /* pipe, fork and execute with exec */
    pipe (pfd);

    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == 0) {
        //child
        close (read_fd);
        dup2 (write_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close (write_fd);
        execl (BASH, BASH, "-c", first, (char *) NULL);
    } 
    else {
        wait (5);
        //parent
        close (write_fd);
        dup2 (read_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
        close (read_fd);
        execl (BASH, BASH, "-c", second, (char *) NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: check the return value of `fopen`, `pipe`,... for possible errors.

Comment: You're trying to connect `bash -c first` and `bash -c second`? Why not just directly `exec` your `first` and `second` commands, and not invoke any shell at all? That is to say, `execl("first", "first", NULL)` and `execl("second", "second", NULL)`. Even if you eventually want to support more than single-word commands, if you only support single-word commands *initially*, that lets you narrow down whether your question is related to the attempts to use a shell interpreter (hint: no, it's not), so you could avoid using that interpreter and thus narrow your question's scope.

Comment: ...which is to say -- the more work you do (parsing, etc), the more vague your question is, and the further it is from complying with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules... or rules on breadth/scoping.

Comment: Both `read_fd` and `write_fd` were assigned the uninitialized values of `pfd[0]` and `pfd[1]` respectively. When `pipe(pfd)` is called, `pfd` gets initialized to a valid descriptor but both `read_fd` and `write_fd` still contain an invalid descriptor. You then attempted to read and write to these descriptor. You can verify this by checking the value of `pfd[0]` and `read_fd` and you will see they differ.

Comment: If you just move the initialization of `read_fd` and `write_fd` after `pipe(pfd)`, your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Note: `main` is type `int` and therefore returns a value. At least add `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks everybody. As alvits has pointed out, the initialization was the problem.